# i want to change the destination of my ActionColumn's button view to the different table in same database

Tags: php, yii2

i want to change the destination of my ActionColumn's button view to the different table in same database...

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

       // 'id',
        'nama_siswa',
        'bahasa_indonesia',
        'bahasa_inggris',
        'matematika',
         'kejuruan',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],

]); ?>
```

Comment: How can i do it?
i'm sorry if my english is still bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Change `view` button url as:- which points to another action controller or url

Change `ActionColumn` Decorator as : -

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

   // 'id',
    'nama_siswa',
    'bahasa_indonesia',
    'bahasa_inggris',
    'matematika',
    'kejuruan',
    [
       'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
       'buttons' => [
           'view' => function(){
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', ['/other-controller/action'], []);
                }
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

]); ?>

Comment: Thank's sir.. but,how if i want to change every button in every row's

Comment: just like `view` you can use `update` and `delete` and also provide own buttons

Comment: oh yes sir.. Thank's
i got it,i'm understand now